# How do I debug or print to console in Munit Haxe?

Tags: intellij-idea, haxe

I'm trying to debug something in Haxe while running Munit. Is there a way I can debug or print to the console information while running my tests?

Comment: Which language are you targeting? For neko it should dump straight to the console, other languages will have issues as they're not running in the console. The only other way would be to send messages to the neko runner (via sockets) and get that to print out to the console.

Comment: I was targeting flash. There's a little grey arrow that you can click for each test that will show all traces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash:
There's a little grey arrow that you can click for each test that will show all traces.

CPP:
haxelib run munit test -cpp
cpp.Lib.print("foo");

Answer (score 0):

To print to JavaScript console (e.g. in MUnit tests), you may run:

```
js.Browser.console.log("Hello world"); 
js.Browser.console.info("Haxe is great!"); 
js.Browser.console.warn("Something could be wrong"); 
js.Browser.console.error("Something went wrong");
```

Source: [HAXE - Debugging in Javascript](https://haxe.org/manual/debugging-javascript.html)